# How to add different weight for different product in wocommerce in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have different products on my e-commerce site.
That has different weights like litter, kg, and ml and etc.
How can set different weights on a different product?
And I want to show it on my product page.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Add custom fields to product shipping tab
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_shipping', 'add_custom_shipping_option_to_products');
function add_custom_shipping_option_to_products(){
    global $post, $product;
    echo '</div><div class="options_group">'; // New option group

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => 'weight_in_grm',
        'label'       => __( 'Weight (gram)', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => 'Weight in gram',
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'set product weight in gram', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'       => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'weight_in_gram_meta', true ),
    ) );
}

// Save the custom fields values as meta data
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_custom_shipping_option_to_products' );
function save_custom_shipping_option_to_products( $post_id ){

    $weight_in_grm = $_POST['weight_in_grm'];
    if( isset( $weight_in_grm ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'weight_in_gram_meta', esc_attr( $weight_in_grm ) );

}

// Show Gram
add_action ('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'show_weight_gram', 20);
function show_weight_gram() {
    global $post;
    $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);
    $weight_in_gram = $product->get_meta('weight_in_gram_meta');
    if(!empty($weight_in_gram)){
        print '<p>Weight: '.$weight_in_gram. ' gm</p>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```